# why are not all array values printed in c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Why if I store array values in variables "temp1" and "temp2" the console only prints the values 2, 2 and 4 ?

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Declaración de arreglos solicitados.
            double[] array6 = { 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3 }; // true

            //Imprimimos resultado de funcion "mismaDiferencia".
            func1(array6);
        }


        static void func1(double[] arr)
        {
            double temp1 = 0;
            double temp2 = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                temp1 = arr[i];
                temp2 = arr[i++];

                Console.WriteLine($"Contienes: {arr[i]}");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your problem is in this line _temp2 = arr[i++];_ you are incrementing the i variable a second time. The first time is in the loop increment. Probably you want _temp2 = arr[i + 1]_ albeit you never use the temps variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in your for loop. You have `i = 0` and also stating that `i` should be less than `arr.Length - 1`. Than will leave one value out in the end.

Try this instead:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
```

You are also incrementing i twice for each loop. Once in the loop and once in the temp2 = arr[i++] line. To do that, you have to remove the last line as you will get an IndexOutOfRangeException on the last iteration:

```
temp2 = arr[i++];
```

Either remove it or adjust your for loop condition to `i < arr.Length - 1`, if for some reason you need to write both values on each iteration.

Comment: Exactly this. His code will skip every other iteration and exclude the last value as well

Comment: No, if you remove the -1 the program will crash with an IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: Why ? If arr.Length returns 10, then the loop will stop on the 10'th iteration, when i == 9.

Comment: @Steve The loop condition is i < arr.Length not i <= arr.Length. In that case, yes, -1 is required :)

Comment: @LietDude and inside the loop you try to access arr[i+1], with a length of arr=10 in the last loop i will be 9 and i+1 will be 10. Your suggestion to remove the -1 will crash the program. Just try it.

Comment: @Steve ah, dang it, you are right, i did not see that. Either way, i would just remove that line entirely, since he is not using it at this point. But you are right :)

Comment: I adjusted my answer accordingly

Comment: I really suggest you to test your answers. Still wrong, still incrementing i two times. It is a mistery how three people upvoted this.

Answer (score 0):

Since  temp2 = arr[i++] increases counter i for 1 without printing it, you will always print only every another one.

And by the way

```
temp2= arr[i++] ;
```

still has the same value as arr[i];

If you want to assign the next value to temp2 you have to use

```
temp2 = arr[++i];
```

So try this

```
    var i=0;
    for ( i =0; i < arr.Length-1; )
    {
        temp1 = arr[i];
        temp2 = arr[++i];
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Contienes: {arr[i-1]}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Contienes: {arr[i]}");
```

Comment: @Steve By the time it goes to Console i is i+1 already. So there is no  i=0 I have to start from1. If i move Console to the top I can use just array[i]

Answer (score -2):

{} is set notation. sets do not contain duplicates. use [] brackets instead.

Comment: Curly brackets are the correct syntax for array initialization in C#.

Comment: This is not correct. In c# you can omit the new [] and just do {}